# Execute stored procedure and update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have requirement where I need to update a table using the results from stores procedure.

Example:

```
Declare @result1 decimal
Declare @price deciaml

Create Table #OrderDetails
{ 
    @orderID bigint
    ,@orderName nvarchar(9)
    ,@orderPrice decimal
    ,@orderFlag nchar(1)
}

Insert into #OrderDetails
{ 
    @orderID 
    ,@orderName 
    ,@orderPrice
    ,@orderFlag
} Select * from CartDetails


Update #OrderDetails
set @orderFlag = 1
from #OrderDetails
where orderID = 1

--Now update each row of #OrderDetails by calling a stored procedure
Update #OrderDetails
set @orderPrice= @result1
from (exec store_proc_calc_price orderID, orderName, @price = @result1 Output)
```

Is there a way to do execute the stored procedure for each row in `#OrderDetails` and update the `@orderPrice` from the result of a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that. you need to create a cursor to loop thru all the lines of the table and call the stored procedure for each line. look at the example for cursor in the help, it is pretty straight forward...

Comment: current implementation has a cursor and I am attempting to remove the cursor.

Comment: what's wrong with the cursor? there is no other way to call a sp for every line of a table...